# Inconsistency between poisson and negativebinomial in glm

Tags: generalized-linear-model, regularization, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression, h2o

I am working with the negativebinomial distribution for GLM. I have done one test which is finding the poisson distribution results. Here is the first test:

```
import h2o
h2o.init()
from h2o.estimators.glm import H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator

h2o_df = h2o.import_file("http://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/glm_test/Motor_insurance_sweden.txt")
# Set the predictor names and the response column
predictors = ["Payment", "Insured", "Kilometres", "Zone", "Bonus", "Make"]
response = "Claims"

negativebinomial_fit = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family="negativebinomial",
                                                     link="log",
                                                     theta=1e-10 ,
                                                     lambda_ = 0.2,
                                                     lambda_search=False,
                                                     alpha=0)

negativebinomial_fit.train(x=predictors, y=response, training_frame=h2o_df)
print(negativebinomial_fit.summary()["regularization"])
print(negativebinomial_fit.predict(h2o_df))

poisson_fit = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family="poisson",
                                            link="log",
                                            lambda_ = 0.2,
                                            lambda_search=False,
                                            alpha=0)

poisson_fit.train(x=predictors, y=response, training_frame=h2o_df )
print(poisson_fit.summary()["regularization"])
print(poisson_fit.predict(h2o_df))
```

In this case they are both giving the same result for the prediction, 16.40,17.18 ...

If I change the lambda_ parameter I have again the same result.

The problem is when lambda_search=True. In this case the optimal lambda_ parameter is totally different. I get 0.05204 for the negativebinomail and 41.008 for poisson. I think it is a bug they should be the same and the prediction as well?
Here is the code:

```
negativebinomial_fit = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family="negativebinomial",
                                                     link="log",
                                                     theta=1e-10 ,
                                                     lambda_ = None,
                                                     lambda_search=True,
                                                     alpha=0)

negativebinomial_fit.train(x=predictors, y=response, training_frame=h2o_df)
print(negativebinomial_fit.summary()["regularization"])
print(negativebinomial_fit.predict(h2o_df))

poisson_fit = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family="poisson",
                                            link="log",
                                            lambda_ =None,
                                            lambda_search=True,
                                            alpha=0)

poisson_fit.train(x=predictors, y=response, training_frame=h2o_df )
print(poisson_fit.summary()["regularization"])
print(poisson_fit.predict(h2o_df))
```

Comment: Thank you. I can understand a small difference but in that case the performance of the model is a lot different and I think it shouldn't. That does not make sense to me. Moreover the gradient can be different but not the optimal value.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the lambda-search difference is due to the fact that the lambda values are chosen from its gradient information.  If the gradient of the two algos differ from each other, you will get the different lambda search values.  I will double check just to make sure.  Thanks, Wendy

Comment: Hi Wendy did you look at the problem please?